# Are the time and space complexity for my algorithm for checking if two strings are permutations of each other correct?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

```
    /*
    Returns true is the two strings are permutations of each other.
    Time Complexity; O(nlog n) -> because of the java utils array sort
    Space Complexity; O(1)
 */
public boolean isPermutationOptimized(String one, String two) {
    if (one.length() != two.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    return sort(one).equals(sort(two));
}

public String sort(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(c);
    return new String(c);
}
```

I believe the time complexity is O(nlogn) because of the java.utils array sort and space complexity is constant.

Comment: Space complexity is incorrect.

Comment: If `one` and `two` were 10MB or 100MB each, how much memory would the algorithm require? Which lines in your snippet would require large space allocations?

Comment: Note you can sort in `O(n)` in this case too.

Comment: How can I sort in O(n) time?

Comment: @DavisWard [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) are often used for sorting strings and sets of small integers. This is an exception to the typical `O(n log n)` sort expectation, because you can simply count/increment (O(1)) for each char (O(n)) and reproduce it in O(n + k) time with `k` as the number of buckets (65536, for 65536 char values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time complexity is O(nlogn) both in avg and in worst case.
Space complexity of Timsort (the used sort algorithm) requires an additional O(n) space: it is not constant complexity but linear complexity.
Some references: https://ericmervin.medium.com/what-is-timsort-76173b49bd16

The complexity of your algorithm is the same complexity of Timsort, because you used two times that algorithm.